# what type of authentication i need to use laravel to magento

Tags: magento2, rest-api, authentication

I want to use Laravel as frontend for Magento 2 . And I want to use Rest API for that.
I have seen below authentication types are there.

1.Session based

2.Token based

3.Oauth based.

Which one I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer 1.Session based and 2.Token based. Because these options are easy to implement. They are also secured. But,  1.Session based only allows for Ajax calls.

> The session based authentication functionality is restricted to only
>   allow for AJAX calls and not direct browser requests due to security
>   vulnerabilities.